# Potentially infinite list of tuples in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, factors

I have a problem I somehow cannot solve. It's the follow up task about divisors.

First one was defining a function that puts all positive divisors of a number *k* into a list

EDIT: Accidentally wrote the wrong code (this is what you get when you have a function divisors and divisor...was just playing arround seeing how the lists react.)
Concerning the problem about having multiples in a list, this shouldn't happen here, but it's way slower.

```
divisor :: Int -> [Int]
divisor k = divisor' 1 k
 where
  divisor' n k  | n > k = []
              | k `mod` n == 0 = (n:result)
              | otherwise = result
   where result = divisor' (n+1) k
```

So far so good.

My following task is to write a function that gives back a list of tuples `(x,xs)` where `x` is a natural number `/= 0` and `xs` is a list of all  positive divisors of `x`.

It should look like that:

```
take 7 trueDivisors 
[(1,[]),(2,[1]),(3,[1]),(4,[1,2]),(5,[1]),(6,[1,2,3]),(7,[1])]
```

(`take` stands for what exactly? that might be my problem now that I re-read the task. Usually functions only get called by their name... tried to get `trueDivisors k` to work)

I've tried quite a bit, like using my first function to get the divisors in the list inside of the tuple, which didn't work out. Syntax error over syntax error.

Maybe someone can help me out a bit, or give me a hint. Sadly there isn't something remotely like that in the script. And google wasn't too keen either.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You want to connect these pieces (1) generate an infinite list `[1,2,3,4,......]` (2) find out how to produce a new list by applying a function to all elements of an old list (3) make a function that given a number, say `x`, return a tuple `(x, divisors x)`.

Comment: [take](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take) just takes n elements from a list. So `take 3 [5,4,7,10,2] == [5,4,7]`

Comment: related question, what does `divisors 25` return?

Comment: are you familiar with the [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) function? and/or, with [list comprehensions](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) syntax? what about list generator syntax, like `[2..10]` or `take 5 [2,4..]`? do you know about [searching by types](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a-%3Eb%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Bb%5D&scope=set%3Astackage)?

Comment: This is nothing but finding prime numbers so you better concentrate on how it is done best.

Comment: divisors 25 
returns [1,5,25], why ?

And thanks for the input, and no, I'm not familiar with map, sadly, as it seems to be the way to go, but tomorrow I'm gonna read up a bit! You gave me some key words to look out for, thanks!

EDIT I uploaded the wrong code, jeez...gonna update now.

Comment: @DewaynClark you're welcome. (use @ to ping someone, so they get notified). you were getting `[1,5,5,25]` with that code, haven't you? BTW you could fix that, without making it so much slower, with some testing to discover this special case.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a hint. If you `map divisors [1..7]`, you get:

```
[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,2,2,4],[1,5],[1,2,3,6],[1,7]]
```

These are the second components of the association list you want to create, except that you have a minor bug unless returning the same divisor multiple times is allowed.  (Hint: you can write a nice one-line version of `divisors` using `filter`, but a quick fix is `Data.List.nub`.) You want to return:

```
[(1,[1]),(2,[1,2]),(3,[1,3]),(4,[1,2,4]),...]`
```

One simple way to solve this problem is to write a helper function `makeAssoc :: Int -> (Int, [Int])` and then `map makeAssoc [1..]`. This function can call `divisors`.

Another is to take the two lists `[1..]` and `(map divisors [1..])`. The first has type `[Int]`, the second has type `[[Int]]`, and you want the result to have type `[( Int, [Int] )]`. So look for a function in the `Prelude` that will zip two lists of types `[a]` and `[b]` into a list of pairs `[(a,b)]`. That is, look for functions with type signature [`[a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%20%5Ba%5D%20%20-%3E%20%5Bb%5D%20%20-%3E%20%20%5B(a%2Cb)%5D&scope=set%3Aincluded-with-ghc) and see if any of them do what you want.

If figuring out the types seems complicated, don’t worry: you can get GHC to do it for you!  If you write,

```
divisorAssocs :: [( Int, [Int] )]
divisorAssocs = map _ is
  where is :: [Int]
        is = [1..]
```

GHC will recognize the `_` as a typed hole, and tell you what you need to fill it:

```
• Found hole: _ :: Int -> (Int, [Int])
```

Similarly if you write it the other way with a hole:

```
divisorAssocs :: [( Int, [Int] )]
divisorAssocs = _ is (map divisors is)
  where is :: [Int]
        is = [1..]
```

Gives you:

```
• Found hole: _ :: [Int] -> [[Int]] -> [(Int, [Int])]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, there isn’t really a difference between finite and infinite lists. The question is asking you to make a variable (although Haskell variables don’t vary) called `trueDivisors` which has type `[(Int, [Int])]`.

Let’s first look at how to make some infinite list

```
myFirstInfiniteList :: [Int]
myFirstInfiniteList = [1..]
powers :: [Int]
powers = powers’ 1 where
  powers’ n = n : n * 2
myThirdInfiniteList :: [(Int,[Int])]
myThirdInfiniteList = map it [1..] where
  it n = (n, [1..n])
```

Now Haskell doesn’t know in advance whether a list is infinite or not so if you try to print one, it will go on forever. So you can use the `take` function which returns the first n elements of a list (where n is the first parameter)

I think this should be enough for you to solve it yourself now.

```
trueDivisors :: [(Int,[Int])]
trueDivisors = {- you need to do this -}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you pair the number and divisors?

One trivial implementation is:

```
pair n = (n, divisors n)
```

what is left is mapping pair to the infinite sequence of natural numbers and take the required number of elements

```
take 7 $ map pair [1..]
```